# How to understand the which GIS server is used?

Tags: web-gis

I want to understand how I can learn the GIS server type of a certain link. In instance I want to know which type of server is being used for http://barajlar.dsi.gov.tr/ web site.

Related server links are http://tilesrv01.dsi.gov.tr/ and spatialsrv01.dsi.gov.tr. Are they using GeoServer, ArcGIS, Mapnik, ..vs?

Comment: It's not always easy to tell what product is in use, but looking at the "Net" tab in Firebug (Firefox extension), I see a reference to /js/openlayers/OpenLayers.js and a bunch of tile gets from mtsN.google.com, so I'd guess OpenLayers

Comment: It is really hard to tell, because there are no relevant error messages returned by the server. The only things I can tell for sure is, that they are using a Windows IIS7 Server and serving [UTFGrids](https://github.com/mapbox/utfgrid-spec), which are not produced by a lot of servers.

Comment: Openlayers seems like the frontend of the application but I am more interested at the server where the data is stored so that I check the WMS and WFS links.

Comment: @UgurIsik: Maybe they don't have no WMS and WFS servers and are just serving tiles (preprocessed or with a tile server). I tried with a GetCapabilities, but there was no response, but you can try different variants and maybe you will have success at some point.

Comment: Is this intended to be a generic question, as in how can I work out which services are being used to provide the data and which clients have been used to show the data, for any web site showing maps, or is it specific to this site?

Comment: For this site, I can say that the client is definitely using OpenLayers for some functionality, and some of the data is being provided by Google Maps.  There appear to be no calls to a OGC web service, but such services could be being used in the background.